# Simulating a Quantum Network over a real Classical Network Using Simulaqron

Tags: programming, simulation, communication, quantum-networks

I'm trying to simulate a quantum network over a real classical network using the Simulaqron framework. I know the documentations says this is possible but I am having trouble finding examples of how to do this exactly. What are the steps to simulating a quantum network over a classical network in Simulaqron?

Also are there other frameworks that can do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add a link to the documentation?

Comment: Hi, here is a link to the documentation, specifically for configuring a network (https://softwarequtech.github.io/SimulaQron/html/ConfNodes.html#configuring-the-network) I have followed the steps under the configuring the network section but still am not able to run it over a classical network on different machines.